# Correct way to filter User-Agents with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've seen 2 ways of to filter user-agents based on part of their string name:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*EventMachine.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*NerdyBot.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*EventMachine.* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*NerdyBot.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

Both having the same result, apparently, but which one of them is correct?

Answer (score 1):

> Both having the same result

No, they don't.

One matches an omitted value, EventMachine, and NerdyBot.

The other matches only EventMachine and NerdyBot

> which one of them is correct?

That depends on what behaviour you want.

Comment: Let me get this straight: So the first one matches an empty user-agent string or any of those 2: EventMachine or NerdyBot and the 2nd one matches EventMachine or NerdyBot?